# Flask Not Detected in Virtual Environment even though the module is installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, backend, virtualenv

I'm new to flask, I was following a youtube tutorial on how to use flask. I listened and followed the steps carefully (Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1RJmh_OqeA).

1. I installed the virtualenv module using pip
2. Created a virtualenv called Flask
3. Activated the environment and my terminal showed "(Flask)"
4. Installed flask and sqlalchemy using "pip3 install flask flask-sqlalchemy"
5. Created a file called app.py

Contents of the file

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

6. Tried running the file using "python3 app.py"

It throws the error:

(Flask) λ python3 app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Desktop\Flask Intro\Flask\app.py", line 1, in 
from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'

I even checked my list of installed packages using "python -m pip list", it is there:

Package           Version

---

blinker           1.6.2
click             8.1.4
colorama          0.4.6
Flask             2.3.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy  3.0.5
greenlet          2.0.2
itsdangerous      2.1.2
Jinja2            3.1.2
MarkupSafe        2.1.3
pip               23.1.2
setuptools        67.7.2
SQLAlchemy        2.0.18
typing_extensions 4.7.1
Werkzeug          2.3.6
wheel             0.40.0

Been trying for quite some time, any sort of help is appreciated. Thank you : - )

I tried installing multiple other ways like with uppercase and lowercase. I even used pip instead of pip3. I don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to this problem,

Instead of running it with the command "python3 filename.py"

I used the command "flask --app filename run" to run the server.

It works now...